# Simple HTML dom scrape price and save it to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script with Simple HTML dom,

With this script, i extract the prices from 4 URLS, and put in to a MySQL table.

All ok, but the problem is when the price is for example: 14,70 €, in my table i only receive 14.00, when normally i have to receive in my MySQL table 14.70

My MySQL type row for the prices are DECIMAL(10,2).

What can be wrong?

If i manually update the prices, to 14.70 as in the exemple, it works and it output me 14.70

I use this sql query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (name, price, price1, price2, price3)
        VALUES('$title->plaintext', '$price->plaintext',
               '$price1->plaintext' , '$price2->plaintext' ,
               '$price3->plaintext')";
```

EDIT: Nacho is helping good.
I don't understand why this query:

```
INSERT INTO productos (nombre, nombreFabricante, precio, precioComp1, precioComp2, precioComp3) VALUES('Staa', 'AOs', '38,25 € ', '34,27 € ', '14,70 € ', '21,00 € ')
```

It saved in the MySQL table has:

Staa    AOs 38.00   34.00   14.00   21.00

As you can see, it dont save me decimals of my prices. 38,25 in MySQL db is 38... 34,27 in MySQL db is 34.

Thanks for any help!! Regards

EDIT2: **Nacho** has helped to answer that question right! Good job and really appreciate! Best regards

Comment: mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: Yes, i know, but for the moment i use mysqli. Later i will change to PDO! Thank you for the advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `:
You need to remove the € sign. you can do it this way, you need to change the commas (,) by dot (.) so MySQL gets the number rigth

```
$price_go=str_replace(",",".",str_replace(" €","",$price->plaintext));
$price_go1=str_replace(",",".",str_replace(" €","",$price1->plaintext));
$price_go2=str_replace(",",".",str_replace(" €","",$price2->plaintext));
$price_go3=str_replace(",",".",str_replace(" €","",$price3->plaintext));

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (name, price, price1, price2, price3)
        VALUES('$title->plaintext', $price_go,
               $price_go1, $price_go2,
               $price_go3)";
```

Comment: That's the error it show me if i do as you have adviced :( Thank you for your try

Error: INSERT INTO test (name, price, price1, price2, price3) VALUES(Name, 38,25 € , 14,70 € , 38,25 € , 21,00 €)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Name, 38,25 € , 14,70 € , 38,25 € , 21,00' at line 1

Comment: I have modified the answer

Comment: Wow Nacho!! It had succefully removed the " €" but it still have error on the code

Error: INSERT INTO test (name, price, price1, price2, price3) VALUES(Name, 14,70 , 38,25 , 38,25 , 38,25)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Name, 14,70 , 38,25 , 38,25 , 38,25 )' at line 2

Comment: Hello Nacho, i think i have the error with your code because the prices now are with , instead of . 

This can be the error?? Thanks!

Comment: Try now, i made changes

Comment: Have you tried to make a **print ("<p> $sql </p>"); ** to see the content of $sql? Try it and tell me the result

Comment: Hello Nacho, this is the result error:

Error: INSERT INTO productos (nombre, precio, precioComp1, precioComp2, precioComp3) VALUES('Strawberry Banana', 38,25 , 34,27 , 14,70 , 21,00 )
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I think the error is because of the commas (,) in the prices. Can be right? 

Let me know and thank you best regards

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have made changes in my answer so it replaces the commas (,)  by dots (.)

Comment: Not working, also error, this time :

 Error: INSERT INTO productos (nombre, precio, precioComp1, precioComp2, precioComp3) VALUES('Test', . , . , . , . )  :(:(:(:(

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake, it was in the wrong order for str_replace

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try mysqli or pdo,but i prefer using mysqli,it's simple,maybe this can help you:

```
$con = new mysqli("host","user","password","db");

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (name, price, price1, price2, price3)
        VALUES('$title->plaintext', '$price->plaintext',
               '$price1->plaintext' , '$price2->plaintext' ,
               '$price3->plaintext')";

$con->query($sql);
```

Comment: Nobody else?? The answer from @nacho was the most succesfully